# $f(x,y) = (1- \cos(\frac{x^2}{y})) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y) = (1- \cos(\frac{x^2}{y})) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $y \ne 0$

How can I prove that f is not differentiable in $(0,0)$.
Please some help.

Comment: It's not even defined in $(0,0)$.

Comment: You have different functions in the title and in the body of your question. Should it be $\cos$ or $\cos^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not defined at $(0,0)$, but we can examine the directional derivatives if we define an extension. Consider the extension with $f(0,0)=0$, since the limit of the function is $0$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ along any path with $y\neq0$.

The directional derivative for an arbitrary direction vector $(a,b)$ is

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\,\frac{f(ha,hb)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac1{h}\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{h^2a^2}{hb}\right)\right]\sqrt{h^2a^2+h^2b^2} \\=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\left[1-\cos\left(h\frac{a^2}{b}\right)\right]\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\\ = \begin{cases} 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,b\neq0 \\ \text{undefined}\,\,\text{if}\,\,b=0 \end{cases}. $$

So the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ is $0$ in any direction that is not parallel to the x-axis. Otherwise it is undefined.

Comment: The claim that it is not parallel to the axis is not clear to me.

Here line $y= 3$ is parallel to  $x$ axis  and $D_{(x,y)}f(0,0)=0. $

Comment: In my opinion, $D_{(a,b)}f(0,0)=0 $ in all directions, even when it is parallel to the $x$ axis.

Comment: @jasmine: When $b=0$ the directional derivative is undefined correct?  That is to say approaching $(0,0)$ “along” the x-axis. So in that case “parallel” may not be the best term to use.

Comment: Nevertheless less what I said was the derivative is $0$ when taken along a line that is not parallel to the x-axis. That I believe is correct.

Comment: okay @RRL that means the derivative  is undefined in the  direction  of the unit vector $(1,0)$. Am i right ?

Comment: @jasmine:  You are correct.